# Connect to external MySQL db on Bluehost from apps script

Tags: mysql, database, google-apps-script

I have seen a number of posts relating to this issue, however,  have still not found an answer that works for me.  I'm trying to connect to an external MySQL database on Bluehost, from a Google Apps Script, using Jdbc.getConnection()

I've tried configuring a table with both MyISAM and InnoDB.  In both cases I get the "Failed to connect to the database..." error.  In one of the posts, I saw that someone had set their storage engine version to 5.5.25a.  I looked for how to do that but couldn't find it in the phpMyAdmin interface that Bluehost provides.  They also allow you to write SQL scripts but I couldn't find an SQL syntax example other than "ALTER TABLE [tablename] ENGINE=InnoDB", with no way to specify a version number.

In the code sample below, I don't provide a table name since the getConnection() function is failing anyway.  If I can get the connection to work, I'll be good to go.

Here's my apps script code:

```
function myFunction() {

  var address = '69.195.124.100:3306';
  var user = 'nathany7_usr2';
  var userPwd = 'vom4usr2';
  var db = 'nathany7_test2db';

  var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address + '/' + db;

  try{
    // Write one row of data to a table.
    var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

  ...

    // close database
    conn.close();

  }catch(e){
    return e.message;
  }
```

Comment: I have been able to achieve this using a MySQL hosted on Godaddy.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I just happened upon it now and think I might have the answer. Maybe it will be useful for someone else, if not for OP.

If I understand correctly you are trying to connect to a MySQL database running on your bluehost server from another server. By design, however, Bluehost will block all incoming database connections to it's server (a reasonable security measure methinks)

So you first have to follow the steps here ( https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/89 ) to allow the server you're executing the script on to pass the connection call through Bluehost's firewall.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your link in your actual answer to guard against the link going dead, e c. Many thanks.